# Oracle VM not working after upgrade to Catalina

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, oracle

Prior to installing Catalina, I updated Oracle VM to version 6.1.16. Now after successful OS upgrade my Windows 10 VM is not working.

[image: Oracle VM error]

Comment: From what I can tell it is a file not found error. You may need to go into virtualbox settings and re-add the VM files.

Comment: Ok user did find files will give settings in VM a try thx

Comment: Steve Chambers how do you do that? re-add files to VM settings

Comment: Virtual Box > VM > Settings > Storage. See if re-selecting the drives there help. you can also edit the .vbox settings files with a text editor. You just want to edit or remove items that are no longer there. I am only a casual user. you might be better off on the virtualbox forums.